# How to replicate these matrix using Latex in R Markdown

Tags: r, latex, markdown

I'm a newbie to R and I'm currently writing a markdown for a project. 
However, I'm facing a problem in reproducing the following matrices:

https://imageshack.com/i/f02dxhpHp
https://imageshack.com/i/p1X5khBRp

In particular, can you please tell me how to reproduce the curly brackets?

The code that i wrote so far is:

```
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{A_{eq}} =
\left[ \begin{matrix}
1 & 1 & \ldots
& 1 & & 0 & & 0 & \ldots
& 0 \\
w_1 & w_2 & \ldots
& w_n & & 0 & & 0 & \ldots
& 0\\
\end{matrix} \right] 
\mathbf{a_{eq}} =
\left[ \begin{matrix}
1 \\
\bar{r} \\
\end{matrix} \right] 
\end{equation*}
```

Answer (score 0):

These curly braces are made with the `\overbrace{<you_code>}` command. For deeper informations refer to page 250 of Guit guide (in Italian as your nick name suggest), you can find it [here](http://www.guitex.org/home/it/doc) or the LaTeX section of Stackexchange. For non Italian speakers informations and examples about `\overbrace{}` can be found [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics).

About to translate that code in markdown I see it a very hard task. My advice is to use R markdown and embed LaTeX code (which is the provided code) in it and knit it as PDF. Your code will be rendered well because knitr PDF use pdfLaTeX as underneath engine. Of course if you will try to knit it as HTML you'll have a bad day and output will be a mess with pure LaTeX code not interpreted well.

#### Edit

As Roberto pointed out `\overbrace{<you_code>}` seems to not work with the standard (and "ancient") matrix environment.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer! I tried to use `\overbrace{}` as you said, but it works only I put elements without the `&` inside the brackets i.e:
`\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{A_{eq}} =
\left[ \begin{matrix}
\overbrace{1} & 1 & \ldots
& 1 & & 0 & & 0 & \ldots
& 0 \\
w_1 & w_2 & \ldots
& w_n & & 0 & & 0 & \ldots
& 0\\
\end{matrix} \right] 
\mathbf{a_{eq}} =
\left[ \begin{matrix}
1 \\
\bar{r} \\
\end{matrix} \right] 
\end{equation*}`

Comment: That's why I said that this LaTeX part of the question should be asked here: http://tex.stackexchange.com , anyway knitr it with the `knitr` package as a PDF should not be a problem if you embed the LaTeX code inside the Rmarkdown.